# Check if the specified file already exists in an URL, if yes the keep the older file and upload the newer file also-- using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, upload

I have an URL **https://....//error.txt** .  Firstly I want to check if this URL already exists, if yes I need to upload another file to the same location and name it as **https://....//error_1.txt** again need to check ; if these 2 are already present then name the next upload as **https://....//error_2.txt** and so on. How to accomplish this. I already have the upload function. I have the python file like this

```
with open("../../../error.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("Now the file has more content!")
    f.close()
```

and the upload function contains the source and target locations

```
#upload(source,destination)
upload("C:\DISK_D\Work\error.txt","https://....//error.txt")
```

Comment: You might want to check out the `requests` module.

Comment: Requests module is not installing inspite of using pip install requests and pip3 install requests. getting the following error "ImportError: No module named requests"

Comment: Try ```python -m pip install requests```